# task from eolymp with bad condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a task to solve a rather interesting problem from the eolymp site, here is the link: https://www.eolymp.com/en/problems/7342, please solve the problem 100% in Python and drop the code in your answer.

I have gone through many options to solve this problem but it is too confusing for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can filter then apply the drop. Try:

```py
import pandas
import re

def ismatch(row):
    return bool(re.match(r"\d+/\d{2}", row["Column"]))

df = pandas.read_csv("Dataf.csv")
df = df[df.apply(ismatch, axis=1)].drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```